# Snap , app armor and gimp plugins

Tags: 16.04, snap, plugins, gimp, apparmor

I installed gimp 2.10 using snap in Ubuntu 16.04 32-bit and want extract/move plugins to required directory:

> /home/velukutty/snap/gimp/253/.config/GIMP/2.10/plug-ins

But unable to do so due to apparmor policy:

```
Can't show file in file manager: Calling ShowItems failed: 
GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: An AppArmor policy 
prevents this sender from sending this message to this recipient; 
type="method_call", sender=":1.136" (uid=1000 pid=5802 
comm="/snap/gimp/253/usr/bin/gimp ") 
interface="org.freedesktop.FileManager1" 
member="ShowItems" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" 
destination=":1.72" (uid=1000 pid=1441 comm="nautilus -n ")
```

My concern is;

- Is there a way to resolve this error?
- Also is there a single command to extract plugins directly into required folder? Or how to access the required folder?

Comment: Try putting them in ~/snap/gimp/current instead of inside a specific version (~/snap/gimp/253). Also check out previous discussion on this specific topic: https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/gimp-plugins-from-third-parties/8391/

Comment: No this doesn't work I was able to open file locations using ```xdg-open location``` and copied them to even .config folder and even mentioned them in preferences I am using Ubuntu 16.04 32-bit pc does this change anything ?

Comment: The problem is with plug-ins rather than the location seems that plug-ins downloaded from github has some error (mostly compilation i think since it doesn't show up as python app but as text file)